# django - get values from formset

Tags: python, django

I've tried to get value from formset do some calculations and pass the output.
My code is:

```
    def form_valid(self, form, formset):

        rndid2 = RndIds()

        form.instance.doc_added_by = self.request.user
        form.instance.doc_guid = rndid2.random_doc_guid()

        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            cd = instance.cleaned_data()
            at_id=cd.get('att_guid')
            instance.att_added_by = str(self.request.user)
            instance.att_ctrl_sum = rndid2.random_doc_application_id(at_id)
            instance.save()
        
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

But got an error

```
 'Att' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

Att is my model

How can I get the formset values?

Comment: I think you haven't call the `super()` and update the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, once you called the [formset save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset) with commit=False. All the returned instances are the objects resulting from the formset. So, since model instances don't have a cleaned_data (only Forms do) property, you get the error.

To solve it, change the `for` to this:

```
for instance in instances:
            at_id=instance.att_guid
            instance.att_added_by = str(self.request.user)
            instance.att_ctrl_sum = rndid2.random_doc_application_id(at_id)
            instance.save()
```